# Должны ли приёмочные тесты быть в том-же репо что и сам продукт?

Tags: тестирование

Должно ли автоматизированное приёмочное тестирование быть в том-же репозитории что и приложение т.е чтобы приложение тестировало само-себя или эти тесты должны идти отдельно чтобы можно было тестировать одним инстансом тестов любой инстанс приложения?
Также может ли приёмочный тест читать базу приложения чтобы получить данные для сверки которых нету в интерфейсе/либо те которые тяжело доставать?

Comment: Кто кому должен?!!! Как вы решите, так и будет.

Answer (score 1):

1. Честно - как вам удобнее. Тут нет каких-то особых плюсов/минусов, поэтому всё зависит от предпочтений конкретной команды.
2. Если эти данные потом сравниваются с результатами работы тестируемого кода(а не как отдельный, независимый кусок, тестирующий сам себя) - да, то вполне можете хранить и вытаскивать их из базы.